# Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list - Katalon

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon studio for automation and I'm getting this error when calling a method. I'm trying to get a timestamp to an input field.

Below is my method

```
String todayDate() {
  Date today = new Date()
  return today.toString()
}
```

Below is the script code I'm trying to call the method to

```
myVar = todayDate()

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('ObjectRepository/ClassNotices/Page_CloudSchool  
              Teacher/input_Heading_noticeHeading'), myVar)
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346233/could-not-find-which-method-init-to-invoke-from-this-list-on-newinstance-in/38346335

Comment: @MS90 this is when you should flag as duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list on newInstance in groovy closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346233/could-not-find-which-method-init-to-invoke-from-this-list-on-newinstance-in)

Comment: I solved this issue by putting the method to a new test case and calling that test case to my script. Thankyou

Comment: @ImaniAbayakoon clever

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the required date format directly to myVar:

```java
String myVar = mydate.format(“MM/dd/yyyy”) 

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('ObjectRepository/ClassNotices/Page_CloudSchool  
              Teacher/input_Heading_noticeHeading'), myVar)
```

This date can be added in multiple fomats, refer this url:
http://www.macinations.com/2018/02/02/working-with-dates-and-date-formatting-in-katalon-studio/